# As a non-EU citizen can I get a resident permit via my EU citizen partner in a third EU country?

Tags: visa, working-visas, eu, belgium, eu-family-member

I am a non-EU citizen and I am living in Belgium via my work visa. I also have a non-Belgian, EU citizen partner that we are living together for 2 years. We both like Belgium and in 2 years I can apply for citizenship so we want to stay in Belgium.

I want to know if I can get a resident and work permit via my partner in Belgium or not? There are many good remote positions that I can easily apply for and the only problem is my current visa is dependent on my job.

Comment: And what if we get married? We both want to get married but we postponed it because of the pandemic.

Comment: Thank you, if you post your comment as an answer I will accept it and I will close this question, a habit that I learned from stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best answered at your registry office where you and your EU citizen partner are registered. If they recognise your civil partnership, then they will issue you a residence permit as a family member of an EU citizen.

> And what if we get married? We both want to get married but we postponed it because of the pandemic.

Then you would definitely get a new residence permit as a family member. But if you both have been registered together (same address) you might be eligible now (depending on Belgium rules for civil partnerships).